# Linux how to remove files in one folder where prefixes don't match another folder?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, command, directory

I want to remove extra files in one folder where the prefix file names don't match those in the other. A simple example will show:

```
folderA
    - frame0001.jpg
    - frame0002.jpg
    - frame0003.jpg
    - frame0004.jpg
    - frame0005.jpg
    - frame0006.jpg
    - frame0007.jpg

folderB
    - frame0001_test.jpg
    - frame0003_test.jpg
    - frame0004_test.jpg
    - frame0005_test.jpg
    - frame0007_test.jpg
```

From `folderA` I want to remove `frame0002.jpg` and `frame0006.jpg` because those `frameXXXX` prefixes don't exist in `folderB`.

How can I do this automatically in 1 command line statement? Assume that the `frameXXXX` format will be the same for all files between both.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` together with the `-exec` option.

A basic format would be `find . -exec sh -c 'echo {} | grep frame' \;`.

Search with `find` in the `folderA` and execute a `rm` if your condition match (or not match). Useful commands are: `sed`, `grep` and `&& rm {}`, `|| rm {}`.

EDIT:

```
find folderA -type f -exec sh -c 'find folderB -type f | grep $(echo {} | grep -Po "frame[0-9]{4}") > /dev/null || echo rm {}' \;
```

Remove the last `echo` to invoke the delete if you like the output.

EDIT: Fixed and/or, if grep does not match with the second find than remove the file.

Comment: Awesome will try !

Comment: I didn't get any output printed to terminal (after making my minor modifications for testing). Any ideas?